# find directory and make symbolic link into hard link in directory

Tags: linux, find, symlink

I want to find a folder in directory and change the symbolic link in these folders into hard link.

I can find all symlink with following command:

```
 find ${DIRECTORY_0} -type d -name "${DIRECTORY_1}" -exec bash -c 'find "$0" -type l -exec echo {\} \;' {} \;
```

The result is list all symlink are found.

If change echo into readlink, it shows the hard link file.

```
 find ${DIRECTORY_0} -type d -name "${DIRECTORY_1}" -exec bash -c 'find "$0" -type l -exec readlink {\} \;' {} \;
```

Once I try the command :

```
find ${DIRECTORY_1} -type l -execdir bash -c ' cp --remove-destination -fR "$(readlink {} && rm {})" {} ' \;
```

that can make all symlink into hard link.

but i want to merge them together, both find ${DIRECTORY_1} in ${DIRECTORY_0} and change symlink in ${DIRECTORY_1} into hard link.

My try:

```
find directory -type d -name "special_folder" -exec bash -c '\
for i do
find "$i" -type l -execdir bash cp --remove-destination -fvR "$(readlink {\} && rm {\})" {\} +
done' bash {} +
```

but show error message

> /bin/cp: /bin/cp: cannot execute binary file

Comment: What for is `bash {} +` at the end of your command?

Comment: I quit for doing this, so there is no answer.